# STL binary_search() implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

An exercise in 'Programming Principles and Practices using C++' asked to implement a STL `binary_search()` function. I did it using recursion, but the program was constantly throwing exceptions. So, I decided to look at the solution, and there was only one thing missing from my implementation. Unfortunately, I cannot understand it why it does.

```
/* binary search for containers with random_access_iterators */
template<class Iter, class T>
bool binary(Iter first, Iter last, const T& val)
{
    if (first == last) return false;                                                        
    Iter middle = first + (last - first) / 2; 
    if (val == *middle) return true;
    if (*middle < val /*??=>*/&& middle+1!=last/*<=??*/) return binary(middle, last, val);
    if (*middle > val) return binary(first, middle, val);
    return false;
}
```

Why was `middle+1!=last` added? What does it do?

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger. There are cases where this code produces an unbounded recursion. Seeing those in action is a valuable lesson in understanding runtime behavior.

Comment: "Why was middle+1!=last added?" because 1/2 == 0

Comment: -1 for not providing sufficient information, not even telling us which exception you got and what you ran this function on. We expect a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to properly answer your questions.

Comment: Interesting, you are doing three comparison per iteration. The related standard algorithm only does one, and only uses `std::less` (or user-provided comparator).

Comment: The solution looks strange to me. I would think that instead of adding `&& middle+1!=last` to the condition, that case should `return binary(middle + 1, last, val);` (add 1 to `middle`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a special case in that particular implementation of binary search. It was added here so that `binary` always terminates.

The second `if` statement always makes the interval shorter, as `middle` is always strictly less than `last`.

The first `if`, however, could sometimes call `binary` with the same arguments. Specifically, that could happen if `first == middle`. And that could happen iff `last - first <= 1`. That happens iff `last - first == 1` (if `last - first == 0`, we've already handled that case separately). That happens iff `middle + 1 == last`.

So, the author decided to handle that case separately. If that happens and `*middle < val`, then we have to return `false`, which is precisely what will happen in that specific implementation: second `if` fails, and last `return false` works.

Here is the same code, rewritten for better clarity (imho):

```
template<class Iter, class T>
bool binary(Iter first, Iter last, const T& val)
{
    if (first == last) return false;                                                        
    Iter middle = first + (last - first) / 2; 
    if (*middle < val) {
        if (last - first == 1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            // first < middle
            return binary(middle, last, val);
        }
    } else if (*middle == val) {
        return true;
    } else {
        // *middle > val
        return binary(first, middle, val);
    }
}
```

I personally don't find that solution elegant, in part because of that weird special case, which can be avoided if the function is rewritten in a slightly different fashion.

For example, one improvement (out of many) is to make the first recursive call from `(middle + 1, last)` instead - as `*middle < val`, it's pointless to include `middle` in our search range. That also guarantees termination

```
template<class Iter, class T>
bool binary(Iter first, Iter last, const T& val)
{
    if (first == last) return false;                                                        
    Iter middle = first + (last - first) / 2; 
    if (*middle < val) {
        return binary(middle + 1, last, val);
    } else if (*middle == val) {
        return true;
    } else {
        // *middle > val
        return binary(first, middle, val);
    }
}
```

Comment: @einpoklum if you're talking about my second approach, there is no harm in making the call as it will check whether there is anything in empty segment and return `false`, as expected.